# Crafting JSON for Multiple Results in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: json, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Custom API to return one or many rows from a table in Json on Azure Mobile Services:

```
exports.post = function (request, response) {
    var tables = request.service.tables;
    var accountSensor = tables.getTable('AccountSensor');
    var item = {
        accountid: request.body.accountid
    }

    accountSensor.where(function (item) {
        return this.accountid == item.accountid;
    }, item).read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.length === 0) {
                response.send(200, {});
            }
            else {
                //for (var sensor in results) {
                //    // Need to return more than one

                //    response.send(200, {
                //        sensors: {
                //            id: sensor.id,
                //            sensorid: sensor.sensorid
                //        }
                //    });
                //}
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I'm a little lost as to how I can construct a JSON to return multiple sets of data, something like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        sensorid: "Lorem"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        sensorid: "Ipsum"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is an array. You can just send that back to yourself. If you want to modify that data first, you an do that, and send your modified results in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Oh good grief, that was simple. Just one line:

`response.send(200, results);`

Comment: Haha, I was about to respond with that answer. Good work!